# ruby nokogiri - scraping contents in nested div

Tags: css, ruby, nokogiri

this is a comment

```html
<div id="md container">
    <ul class="unstyled inline span12"  style="margin-top: … /ul>
        <div id="md_func"
            <ul class"unstyled inline span4 ng-scope"ng-init… 
                <li ng-repeat="event in events" class"span12 ng-scope …
                    <div class="func" ng-class"…
                        <span class="name" event-nowatch="name">XYZ_want_to_get</span>
                        <span class="pull-left address" event-nowatch="address">1234 maries ct</span> 
                   </div>
               </li>
           </ul>   
           </u> … </ul>
           </u> … </ul>
       </div>
</div>
```

How do I get  "XYZ_want_to_get" inside nested div?  I've tried xpath and css combinations, but can never actually get the value "XYZ_want_to_get". I've used inspector to expose paths - and when used output either the node source or nothing.

```
@contents = Nokogiri::HTML(open(url))

puts "css"
puts @contents.at_css('#markdown_functions > ul:nth-child(1) > li:nth-child(1) > div.function > span.name').text

puts "xpath"
puts @contents.at_xpath('//*[@id="markdown_functions"]/ul[1]/li/div[1]/span[1]/text()')

puts "search"
puts @contents.search('//CORE').first.text
```

thanks in advance
dp33

Answer (score 0):

You can get "XYZ_want_to_get" by this:

```
@contents = Nokogiri::HTML(open(url))
@contents.css('span.name').text
```

Proof:

```
2.1.4 :015 > page.css('span.name').text
=> "XYZ_want_to_get"
```

Comment: I can't leave comments below author's post.

Comment: @contents.css('span.name').text was one of the 1st things i tried.
results is - {{ func.cos | cosLabel }} {{ func.name }} which isnt the contents of the attribute.

Comment: If you turn off javascript in your browser, you will see that this is the contents of that attribute. To get content produced by javascript you should use a real browser, for example phantomjs, and selenium or watir-webdriver to control that browser from your ruby app.

Comment: interesting, "func.cos" and "cosLabel" are different elements on the page, in a completely unrelated <div...<div/> how will turning on/off javascript in the browser effect where & what is fetched? thx.

Comment: Turn off javascript in the browser, then load the page and look in the html what is inside that div without js being enabled.
'open-uri' 'open' method can't evaluate javascript. It just gets html from the server.